# Can Kafka consume uncommitted data from oracle?

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka

I know uncommitted changes are definitely contained in the redo logs file in oracle.the question is whether Kafka will consume them as they occur?

I need to read uncommitted data from a particular session in oracle using kafka.

Comment: are you using Kafka with or without Golden Gate ?

Comment: I could work if you used Shareplex. This is something like GoldenGate (but cheaper) and it reads Db changes from redo-logs, forwards them into Kafka. Each message contains transaction ID, and commit is sent as a separate message.

Comment: I am trying to use with golden gate.

Comment: Uncommitted records are not contained in redo logs, because then `insert ... select` will generate as much data as it is in the source table. Oracle uses optimistic approach and inserts/updates new data into the table itself storing the information for rollback in undo tablespace. What is the reason to access uncommitted records? They may never exist in the database

Comment: @astentx, redo entries of uncommitted data are in fact contained in the redo logs. Golden Gate can work with committed and uncommitted data depending on how you are streaming data. If you are using GG as CDC it will discard uncommitted data. But if you use GG as streaming to Kafka, it will contain uncommitted data, however Kafka treats it there I can't answer. But I can assure you GG treats uncommitted data when transfer redo log entries to consumers in streaming mode.

Comment: From Oracle docs: `log writer is writing committed and uncommitted transactions from the redo log buffer to the log files more or less continuously - not just on commit (when the log buffer is 10mb full, 1/3 full, every 3 seconds or every commit - whichever comes first - those all trigger redo writes.`

Comment: @moin, if you are using GG, yes, uncommitted data is streamed to Kafka. However, I can't tell you exactly how Kafka will read it, or whether is need a special configuration for it.

Comment: @ibre5041, there are many products that can read redo logs entries, but most of them either contain bugs and problems and many restrictions. The reason is that all these tools are using reverse engineering techniques to deconstruct the messages within the redo entries, as such  information is protected by Oracle. If you have Golden Gate, you can be sure you are using the best tool for the job, although it is clear that is also very expensive

Comment: @astentx, of course it is not. It is the instructions to recover such data. Redo entries contain messages which Golden Gate uses to transfer data in streaming to any consumer. Being that the case, uncommitted transactions are moved to the streaming process to be consumed ( you can configured to not do it ). In that case, GG reads the entries in the redo log and recovers the blocks which is the data itself. Obviously I am talking only when GG is configured as streaming to Kafka or consumers.  In normal Change Data Capture mode , GG don't transfer uncommitted data.

Comment: @moin, do you have Kafka connected to GG as streaming ? or by using Change Data Capture ?

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez  I have not configured GG yet with Kafka. But I am thinking about how I am going to configure the way we can stream uncommitted data to Kafka.

Comment: keep in mind that after streaming uncommitted transactions ( either because they are going to rollback or commit later ) there will be an additional message with the final commit/rollback. You have to handle it properly in Kafka to avoid issues.